# Create a grouped bar plot using seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, grouped-bar-chart

I have a dataframe as below

```
category val1 val2 val3
A       2    3     2
A       3    4     1
B       4    5     2
C       3    3     2
B       4    5     2
C       3    3     2
```

I am trying to create a grouped bar visual that has category in the x-axis, and val1, val2, val3 as y-axis.

my code is similar to this:

```
plt.bar(df['category'], df['var1'])
plt.bar(df['category'], df['var2'])
plt.bar(df['category'], df['var3'])
```

however, I didn't get a grouped bar graph. It is something like this. Is there anyway to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Your categories aren't unique, so what would you expect to see on the x-axis?

Comment: Is there anyway to make this category unique

Comment: Do you want to group them somehow or remove duplicates? I don't know your context.

Comment: Your question is related to pandas, your tags say matplotlib, your title mentions seaborn - what are you looking for? And as Kris already said - what should happen with your duplicate categories? Should they be aggregated as sums or means or appear multiple times?

Comment: Sorry, I am not looking for a stacked bar, but rather a grouped bar. So green, yellow, and blue section should be horizontal

Comment: The default is not stacked, so just remove this from the code kindly provided by Kris. But what should happen with the duplicate categories?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is what you are after, but you can try these two options:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import seaborn as sns

data = """category val1 val2 val3
A       2    3     2
A       3    4     1
B       4    5     2
C       3    3     2
B       4    5     2
C       3    3     2"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep="\s+")

g = sns.barplot(
    data=df.melt(id_vars = ["category"], value_vars=["val1", "val2", "val3"]),
    y="value", x="variable", hue="category", ci=None
)
```

[image]

or

```py
g = sns.catplot(
    data=df.melt(id_vars = ["category"], value_vars=["val1", "val2", "val3"]),
    kind="bar",
    y="value", x="variable", col="category", ci=None
)
g.set_axis_labels("", "")
```

[image]

The key to these approaches is to use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to unpivot your data.

Note also that the above is not dealing with your duplicate categories. If you want your values to be unique, you can group your `df` by `category` and aggregate values before plotting.

Answer (score 0):

Your categories aren't unique. What do you want to see on the x-axis?

Suppose they were unique, then you could simply do:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['category'] = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
df['val1'] = [2,3,4,3,4,3]
df['val2'] = [3,4,5,3,5,3]
df['val3'] = [2,1,2,2,2,2]

df.set_index('category').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

---

Edit: `seaborn` doesn't support stacked bar charts natively, but here's a hacky way if you need to (or if others are looking for what's actually in the title).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['category'] = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
df['val1'] = [2,3,4,3,4,3]
df['val2'] = [3,4,5,3,5,3]
df['val3'] = [2,1,2,2,2,2]

# create total columns
df['v1+v2+v3'] = df.val1 + df.val2 + df.val3
df['v1+v2'] = df.val1 + df.val2

# plot total
g = sns.barplot(x=df['category'], y=df['v1+v2+v3'], color='green', label='val3')

# plot middle values
g = sns.barplot(x=df['category'], y=df['v1+v2'], color='orange', label='val2')

# plot bottom values
g = sns.barplot(x=df['category'], y=df['val1'], color='blue', label='val1')

# rename axes
g.set_ylabel('vals')
g.set_xlabel('categories')

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: The title of the question asks for seaborn, no? Or did you mean my answer doesn't explicitly use seaborn to plot?

Comment: Fair enough, made an edit to reflect what's actually being asked in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I am not looking for a stacked bar, but rather a grouped bar. So green, yellow, and blue section should be horizontal